# Embed twitter feed on Jekyll page?

Tags: twitter, embed, jekyll, feed

I am trying to embed a twitter feed on a static site generated using Jekyll. I am wondering whether Jekyll supports these feeds, as when I try to embed them, nothing appears except the name of the feed. There is very little on the twitter site as it appears you should just copy the code and that's it.

Am I doing something wrong?

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/hashtag/sistersuncut" data-widget-id="765713533543845888"></a>
<script>
!function(d,s,id){
    var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';
    if(!d.getElementById(id)){
        js=d.createElement(s);
        js.id=id;
        js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);
    }
}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");
</script>
```

Comment: Do you have `_config.yml` in your file ..Im Sure you would have

Comment: @nohands kindly check with my answer and do let em know if any you don't get it.

Comment: Wait - are you saying the config.yml file should be somewhere other than the project file it appeared it when I generated the site?

Comment: `_config.yml` used to generate whenever any project will be created with `jekyll`. For your reference [vgvinay2 Github](https://github.com/vgvinay2/vgvinay2.github.io)

Comment: Okay - are you saying I'm supposed to do something with this yml file? I have left it where it is.

Comment: Check out this post: http://keitaito.com/blog/2017/01/20/embedding-tweets-in-github-pages.html

Answer (score 0):

you could use this way as well.

```
<a aria-label="Share on Twitter" href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=&quot;{{ page.twitter_text }}&quot;%20{{ site.url }}{{ page.url }}%20via%20&#64;{{ site.twitter_username }}&hashtags={% for tag in page.tags %}{{tag}},{% endfor %}"
  onclick="window.open(this.href, 'twitter-share', 'width=550,height=235');return false;" title="Share on Twitter">
  <svg class="icon icon-twitter"><use xlink:href="#icon-twitter"></use></svg>
</a>
```

Just defiled `twitter_text`, `twitter_text` and other if you want to use them.
Hope this help you!.

Comment: A square appears on the page and that's it, presumably because there is no feed going into it from the code above..? I can't understand why the images / tweets aren't showing.

Comment: Also what do you mean by 'defiled'?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the twitter widget doesn't actually work anymore. The twitter site that allows you to make widgets is still up for some reason, which is hugely misleading, but there are tons of tweets all saying that since whatever new update, the widgets don't work.